# how to divide an interval into equal parts

Tags: algorithm, math, autoit

Hi how to divide an interval into  equal parts
example :

```
[1-100] divide by 5 part -->

1- [1-20]
2- [21-40]
3- [41-60]
4- [61-80]
5- [81-100]
```

or

```
[1-102] divide by 5 part -->

1- [1-20]
2- [21-40]
3- [41-60]
4- [61-80]
5- [81-100]
6- [100-102]*
```

i try a code but sometimes work and in other nums not work as it must
this is what i make (i know i am week in math :P , i code it 2 week ago and now i have no idea how i make it :D  )

---

```cpp
Func vall($a , $b)
    Local $inval = ''
    $all  = $a
    $c    = $b ; - 1

    $evv  = Int($all/$c)
    $rrt  = Int($all/$evv)

    $trtr = $evv
    $ee   = 1
    $fg   = 0

    If Mod($a,$evv) == 0 Then
        For $ll = 1 To $rrt ; $all
            If $ll = $rrt Then
                $inval = $inval & $ee & ':-:' & $trtr
            Else
                $inval = $inval & $ee & ':-:' & $trtr &','
            EndIf

            $ee   = $ee   + $evv
            $trtr = $trtr + $evv
        Next
    Else
        For $ll = 1 To $rrt ; $all
            $inval = $inval & $ee & ':-:' & $trtr &','
            $ee    = $ee   + $evv
            $trtr  = $trtr + $evv
        Next
        $uu    = $trtr - $evv + 1
        $inval = $inval & $uu & ':-:' & $all
    EndIf

    Return $inval
EndFunc
```

---

i use autoit , but i need the algorithm to use it in any lang .

thank you .

Comment: Make sure to use comments from next time whenever you write code. That will help you in practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a python implementation which is quite easy to understand.

```
def divide(number, parts):
    '''number is the last number of the range and parts is no. of intervals you
        want to make'''
    chunksize = number//parts             # size of each interval
    chunkstart = 1                        # start of interval
    chunkend = chunkstart + chunksize -1  # end of that interval
    while chunkstart < number:            # don't go beyond the range
        if chunkend > number:             # interval end is beyond the range
            print chunkstart, number
            break                         # we are beyond the range now
        print chunkstart, chunkend
        chunkstart += chunksize           # take me to beginning of next interval
        chunkend += chunksize             # also tell me where to end that

Sample Input and Ouputs

divide(100, 5)
1 20
21 40
41 60
61 80
81 100

divide(102, 5)
1 20
21 40
41 60
61 80
81 100
101 102
```

Comment: ah i get it it must be : $number >= $parts * 2 true to work corectly . coz Int($number/$parts ) must be > 1 . i am weak in math so that what i think . how ever thank u aloot u make me save a loot of time . (y) ,

Comment: @max any combination of positive integers on the function will work. Like when you do `divide(57, 30)` then you want 30 `equal intervals` from 1 to 57. All those 30 intervals must be size 1 in this case as the range can't occupy intervals of size two. Even when you do `divide(27,30)`, you will get 30 equal intervals each of size 0. So there is no specific condition which needs to be true. Analyse the output and understand that this is what you asked for i.e. equal intervals and you are getting the same. The size of each interval and the leftover chunk are not related.

Comment: yeh , i make a new code (_in new answer_) , but do i will always get a num make this Mod($number,$parts) > Int($number/$parts ) = true , or in some spicial number i will stay in the (while $yusf = 0) loop .?

Answer (score 0):

@pulkit-goyal as u said i did same analyse [your code helped me to understand how it work after all the math is sweet :D ]
so i get that the best way to get the right result 
is to change the parts , and test part-1 and part+1 until it get the best part

i cook a simple code :

```cpp
$number = 57
$parts  = 30
$yy     = 0
$yusf   = 0

ConsoleWrite('number :' & $number & ' | parts : ' & $parts & @CRLF)
$partsplus  = $parts
$partsmoins = $parts

If Mod($number, $parts) > Int($number / $parts ) Then
    While $yusf = 0
        $partsplus  += 1
        $partsmoins -= 1

        If Mod($number, $partsplus) < Int($number / $partsplus ) Then
            ConsoleWrite("old part : " & $parts & "| new part :" & $partsplus & " | interval : " & Int($number / $partsplus ) & @CRLF)
            $parts = $partsplus
            $yusf  = 1
        ElseIf Mod($number, $partsmoins) < Int($number / $partsmoins ) Then
            ConsoleWrite("old part : " & $parts & "| new part :" & $partsmoins & " | interval : " & Int($number / $partsmoins  ) & @CRLF)
            $parts = $partsmoins
            $yusf  = 1
        EndIf
    WEnd
EndIf

$chunksize  = Int($number / $parts )      ; size of each interval
$chunkstart = 1                           ; start of interval
$chunkend   = $chunkstart + $chunksize -1 ; end of that interval

While $chunkstart <= $number              ; don't go beyond the range
    If $chunkend > $number Then           ; interval end is beyond the range
        ; print $chunkstart, $number
        ConsoleWrite("[ " & $chunkstart & " : " & $number & " ]*" & @CRLF)
        ExitLoop
    EndIf

    ; we are beyond the range now
    ConsoleWrite("[ " & $chunkstart & " : " & $chunkend & " ]" & @CRLF)
    $yy         += 1
    $chunkstart += $chunksize             ; take me to beginning of next interval
    $chunkend   += $chunksize             ; also tell me where to end that
WEnd
```

some test
for 57 - 30 , 30 changed to 28 to have good results

```
number :57 | parts : 30
old part : 30| new part :28 | interval : 2
[ 1 : 2 ]
[ 3 : 4 ]
[ 5 : 6 ]
[ 7 : 8 ]
[ 9 : 10 ]
[ 11 : 12 ]
[ 13 : 14 ]
[ 15 : 16 ]
[ 17 : 18 ]
[ 19 : 20 ]
[ 21 : 22 ]
[ 23 : 24 ]
[ 25 : 26 ]
[ 27 : 28 ]
[ 29 : 30 ]
[ 31 : 32 ]
[ 33 : 34 ]
[ 35 : 36 ]
[ 37 : 38 ]
[ 39 : 40 ]
[ 41 : 42 ]
[ 43 : 44 ]
[ 45 : 46 ]
[ 47 : 48 ]
[ 49 : 50 ]
[ 51 : 52 ]
[ 53 : 54 ]
[ 55 : 56 ]
[ 57 : 57 ]*
```

for 7 - 300 , 300 changed to 7 :D

```
number :7 | parts : 300
old part : 300| new part :7 | interval : 1
[ 1 : 1 ]
[ 2 : 2 ]
[ 3 : 3 ]
[ 4 : 4 ]
[ 5 : 5 ]
[ 6 : 6 ]
[ 7 : 7 ]
```

and in normal case
for 10 -2 , no change

```
 number :10 | parts : 2
 [ 1 : 5 ]
 [ 6 : 10 ]
```